# Values changing in C stack implementation

Tags: c, pointers, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack in C, but whenever new data is added, the old values get overridden. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct snode {
    int data;
    struct snode *prev;
    struct snode *next;
};

static struct snode stack;
static struct snode *stackpointer = NULL;

void push(int data) {
    if(stackpointer == NULL) {
        stack.data = data;
        stack.prev = NULL;
        stack.next = NULL;
        stackpointer = &stack;
        return;
    }

    struct snode newnode;
    newnode.data = data;
    newnode.prev = stackpointer;
    newnode.next = NULL;
    stackpointer = &newnode;
}

int pop() {
    int retdata = stackpointer->data;
    if(stackpointer->prev == NULL) {
        stackpointer = NULL; 
    }
    else {
        stackpointer = stackpointer->prev;
        stackpointer->next = NULL;
    }
    return retdata;
}

int peek() {
    return stackpointer->data;
}
```

Whenever a new node is declared in push, the data is changed in all previous values of the stack. Is there something I don't know about pointers that causes them to randomly change value?

EDIT: This new code works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct snode {
    int data;
    struct snode *prev;
    struct snode *next;
};

static struct snode *stackpointer = NULL;

void push(int data) {
    struct snode *newnode = (struct snode*)malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->prev = stackpointer;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    stackpointer = newnode;
}

int pop() {
    int retdata = stackpointer->data;
    if(stackpointer->prev != NULL) {
        stackpointer = stackpointer->prev;
        free(stackpointer->next);
    }
    else {
        free(stackpointer);
        stackpointer = NULL;
    }

    return retdata;
}

int peek() {
    return stackpointer->data;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `push()` function `stackpointer` is being assigned the address of a local variable. After the function returns `stackpointer` will be a dangling pointer as `newnode` will no longer be valid. Dynamically allocate new nodes for the stack using [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc):

```
struct snode* newnode = malloc(sizeof(*newnode));
```

Don't mix the storage of elements in the stack as on first call to `push()` the `stackpointer` is being assigned to address of `stack`. To correctly implement the stack you need to dynamically allocate the nodes which you must also [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free). Passing the address of `stack` to `free()` is invalid. Keep the usage of the stack consistent to avoid complications: always dynamically allocate the nodes and always free the nodes.

Comment: Ahh, thanks a lot. I had seen this done before, but now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

In push, you need to create a new node each time.

CHange this:

```
struct snode newnode;
```

to:

```
struct snode *newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct snode));
```

and then change `newnode.` to `newnode->`.

As it stands, the variable `newnode` only exists inside the function `push` - as it happens, it never gets badly overwritten, or your question would be "why does my program crash weirdly when I call `pop()`. And as long as `push` is called from  the same function in the code, it will use the same location on the stack, so every time you add another item to the stack, it overwrites your old value held in the same (soon to be "unused") location on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `malloc` to allocate a new node.
You're just creating it inside `push` and it will get clobbered the next time `push` (or any other routine) is called.

By the way, you don't need the `next` pointer, only `prev`.